# iOS. In-App-Purchase mysterious error

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have In-App-Purchase in my app. I have enabled it few days ago and it worked all these days. But today weird thing started to happen. It still works perfectly on simulator but it stopped working on a device. This is how it looks - i launch the app (i have to note that i'm not signed in in any iTunesConnect account in Settings so this is not a kind of common error), then i successfully receive my products from StoreKit, then i tap BUY button and StoreKit shows me standard alert "Do you want to buy", i click YES, everything is OK, i'm prompted to enter test user credentials and after i did it transaction fails few seconds later with error code 0, and description "Cannot connect to iTunes". What the hell is that??? It works like a charm in simulator, why it's happening on a device? I have created another test user but it didn't help. I just don't know what else to try. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Did you upload your binary for review on iTunesConnect? Testing only works while you are preparing the binary.

As soon as you tell iTunesConnect you are ready to upload, and the status goes to "waiting for upload" or beyond, the test account will no longer work.

If you are not actually ready and still want to test in-app purchases, you can upload any binary, and then immediately reject it. The status will change to "Developer rejected" and you can resume testing in-app purchases again.

Comment: i didn't upload my binary and still it worked for several days. You don't need to upload your binary to test in-app-purchase. i know that cause this is my third app which uses in-app-purchase and i've always tested it without uploading binary

Comment: Exactly. As soon as you tell iTunesConnect that you are ready to upload your binary, in-app purchase testing will no longer work, and will fail with exactly the message you describe "Cannot Connect to iTunes". What status does your app have within iTunesConnect?

Comment: Hmmm, so you're good there. How about which iTunes account are you signed in with under Settings >> iTunes and App Store? If you recently bought something with your real AppleID it will use that one to attempt the test download, which would also fail.

Comment: and one other possibility... You have network connectivity, right? not  in airplane mode or wi-fi disabled?

Comment: Internet is on and i've signed out of any iTunes account

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41029/discussion-between-ryan-cumley-and-andrey-chernukha)